# Why is building a table of function values so much slower than just plotting the function?

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Here is a function that take some time to evaluate:

```
n = 1000;
coeffs = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n];
f[x_] := Sum[coeffs[[k]] Sin[k x]/k, {k, 1, n}];
```

If I just plot the function with 1000 sample points, it takes about 0.24 seconds on my machine:

```
Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> n, MaxRecursion -> 0] // Timing
```

On the other hand, if I try to collect 1000 samples of the function into a table, it takes *five times as long*:

```
Table[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n // N}] // Timing
```

(Without the `// N` Mathematica tries to evaluate things symbolically, which is even slower.)

What is going on, and how can I make the `Table` as fast as the `Plot`?

Comment: You can save about one-third of the time by removing the redundant `Evaluate` from your `Table` expression. Also, this result is entirely dependent on the `MaxRecursion` setting. If you remove this, or leave it in but increase its value, the plot takes longer than the table.

Comment: I used `MaxRecursion -> 0` expecting that the `Plot` would evaluate exactly 1000 regularly spaced sample points, just like the `Table`. (Well, the `Table` actually evaluates 1001 points, but close enough.) Is that not true?

Comment: I've read in few places that `Table` can be slow. Not sure why now. Yes, you are right, `MaxRecursion -> 0` makes sure no more points are taken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = 1000;
coeffs = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n];
f[x_] := Sum[coeffs[[k]] Sin[k x]/k, {k, 1, n}];
Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2. Pi}, PlotPoints -> n, MaxRecursion -> 0,
   Mesh -> All] // Timing
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[{n = 1000},
 First@Timing[Table[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2. Pi, 2. Pi/n}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

2 times as fast as plot. I remembered my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709170/difference-of-speed-in-making-a-table) `difference-of-speed-in-making-a-table` on tables some time ago and this trick of making `Table` much faster. The point is : to keep it packed, need to have all limits be numerics !  When you had `n` in there, the upper limit was not. So the table was not packed. Now it is.

You could just also write

```
Table[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2. Pi, 2. Pi/1000}]
```

and get the speed advantage. The point again, all its limits needs to be numeric. See above question for more information and additional links on this subject.

### Another example

2000 points. Table still about 2 times faster:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! But for me it seems that the difference is not the presence of `n` or the addition of `With`. Doing `First@Timing[Table[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2. Pi, 2. Pi/n}]]` is fast while doing `First@Timing[Table[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2. Pi/n}]]` as in my question is slow. (The difference is just one more decimal point.)

Comment: @Rahul I'm using v7 so I can't check; is the output of `RandomVariate` a packed array of `Real` numbers?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'm just learning about packed arrays just now, so let me know if this is not how to check: `PackedArrayQ` is `True` and the `Head` of the first element is `Real`, so yes?

Comment: @RahulNarain That's correct.  I added an answer that you'll have to test yourself but it might be informative.

Comment: Having read your linked question I see that `With` is necessary for multidimensional tables, which I *will* need in the future, so thanks for that too! Unfortunately I have already given you an upvote and a check mark, so all I can do now is leave an appreciative comment. :)